# My Instagram bot doesn't like any post and ends the session with KeyError: 0

Tags: python, keyerror, instapy

I am making my first Instagram bot, but it's not working completely. It stops working just before liking the post.

This is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aniket\PycharmProjects\insta_bot1\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    session.like_by_tags(['photography', 'lighting', 'nature'], amount = 3)
  File "C:\Python3.9\lib\site-packages\instapy\instapy.py", line 1957, in like_by_tags
    inappropriate, user_name, is_video, reason, scope = check_link(
  File "C:\Python3.9\lib\site-packages\instapy\like_util.py", line 633, in check_link
    media = post_page[0]["shortcode_media"]
KeyError: 0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my code.

```
from instapy import InstaPy

session = InstaPy(username = 'insta_bot._1', password = '####')
session.login()

session.set_relationship_bounds(enabled = True, max_followers = 150)

session.set_do_follow(True, percentage = 100)
session.like_by_tags(['photography', 'lighting', 'nature'], amount = 3)

session.end()
```

Please help me in resolving the error.

Comment: Take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/issues/6191) for ideas if you haven't already

Comment: I did but I have no idea what to do or what changes should I make. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and it stems from Instagram changing place in website source where they store post information that your InstaPy bot looks for (I am an InstaPy newbie also, please don't judge me too harshly on the specificity of this answer).

It has been fixed in the [issue](https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/issues/6191) linked by [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4583620/michael-ruth) and it has been merged to InstaPy master on GitHub, but it wasn't included in the newest release of the library that I downloaded using IDE.

The easiest thing you can do right now (short of waiting for a new release of the package, that will include those changes) is to download the master from [here](https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy) and substitute files on your computer (or wherever you create that bot) with those from instapy folder within repo you downloaded.

[Here](https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/pull/6195) you can find more information about the fix.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
Edit the file "instapy/like_util.py" , from line: 619 with the code:

```
media = post_page['items'][0]
is_video = media["is_unified_video"]
user_name = media["user"]["username"]
image_text = media["caption"]["text"]
owner_comments = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

So i found the problem, its due to instagram cause they changing the source code. so go to `like_util.py` file then line `619`

then change the code by this:

```
 media = post_page ['items'] [0]
 is_video = media ["is_unified_video"]
 user_name = media ["user"] ["username"]
 image_text = media ["caption"] ["text"]
 owner_comments = "",
 user_nmame,
```